# Logging and error middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

I'm looking for code review on the following basic log/error middleware. The logging middleware uses `logger.js` which has a bunch of methods like `log.error()` (which makes a request out to error tracking service like Sentry).

The `handleErrors` middleware is intended to handle any errors that occur in any of the api routes. So, for example, I have a route `/api/users` and if an error occurs in that request, the `catch` will execute and pass along the error to the `handleErrors` middleware.

```
const getUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  return apiHttpClient.get(req, '/api/users')
    .then(users => res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(users))
    .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

The error middleware should create an error context for the client without exposing the specific error. So for example, if a 400 error occurs, the message sent to the browser would look like:

```
{
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400
}
```

But depending on if the `NODE_ENV` is production, the logging middleware should log out the specific error:

```
{
  "name":"Example",
  "hostname":"",
  "pid":18322,
  "level":40,
  "payload":{
    "name":"BadRequest",
    "message":"A specific error message",
    "statusCode":400,
    "errorCode":400
  },
  "msg":"400: A specific error message",
  "time":"2017-10-22T15:26:06.824Z",
  "v":0
}
```

**Usage**

**express.js**

```
const { logErrors, handleErrors } = require('./errorMiddleware');

// other middleware
// api routes

app.use(logErrors())
app.use(handleErrors());
```

**errorMiddleware.js**

```
const log = require('../../logger');
const HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

const isServerError = (statusCode) => {
  return statusCode >= HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
};

const isProdEnv = (env) => {
  return env === 'production';
};

const getStatusCode = (statusCode) => {
  return statusCode || HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
};

const createErrorContext = (statusCode) => {
  return {
    message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(statusCode),
    status: statusCode
  };
};

const createErrorMessage = (err) => {
  const statusCode = getStatusCode(err.statusCode);
  return `${statusCode}: ${err.message}`;
};

const deleteErrorStack = (env, err) => {
  if (isProdEnv(env)) delete err.stack;
};

const getLogLevel = (statusCode) => {
  return isServerError(statusCode) ? 'error' : 'warn';
};

const logErrors = () => {
  return (err, req, res, next) => {
    const statusCode = getStatusCode(err.statusCode);
    const logLevel = getLogLevel(statusCode);
    const errMessage = createErrorMessage(err);
    const extraData = req.path;

    log[logLevel](errMessage, err, extraData);

    next(err);
  };
};

const handleErrors = () => {
  return (err, req, res, next) => {
    const statusCode = getStatusCode(err.statusCode);
    const errorContext = createErrorContext(statusCode);

    deleteErrorStack(req.app.get('env'), err);
    res.status(statusCode).json(errorContext);
  };
};

module.exports = {
  logErrors: logErrors,
  handleErrors: handleErrors
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Consider making your middleware package into a proper (private?) npm package and consume it as such in the main application. This would also allow better reuse across other applications that may need this behavior.
- `const log = require('../../logger');` This relative reference seems problematic. I would guess your logger should also be a proper npm package (or in same package as your middleware if this is a custom logger).  At a very minimum, I would think you would want to use `path` or similar to get to an absolute file reference based on the location of your middleware file to the working directory.
- Your methodology for determining 'production' environment seems fragile. Why is it up to your middleware package to have a hard-coded string in it that determines whether production behavior is to be expressed?
- The `deleteErrorStack()` function seems superfluos and actually obfuscates the logic of what is happening in the `handleErrors` function.  Why not just have this single line of code inside the `handleErrors` function so intent is much clearer.

For example:

```
const handleErrors = () => {
  return (err, req, res, next) => {
    const statusCode = getStatusCode(err.statusCode);
    const errorContext = createErrorContext(statusCode);

    if(isProdEnv(req.app.get('env')) {
        delete err.stack;
    }
    res.status(statusCode).json(errorContext);
  };
};
```

- One could possibly argue that the deletion of the stack trace information from `err` is logic this should exist within your context creation method, as this is really a display concern, not an error handling concern.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! Do you know if I even have to delete the err.stack? Will express automatically suppress it if the NODE_ENV is set to "production"?